# 404 Not Found nginx /1.18.0 aws laravel project

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I had uploaded a laravel 7 project MONTHS ago and it was working fine but now for some reason my `/` route is working fine but  as I hit login this error shows up:-

> 404 Not Found
> nginx/1.18.0

I have pointed the documented root to public folder.

 Can anyone help me I am just a beginner.

Comment: sounds like url rewriting/pretty urls is not working

Comment: @lagbox Sorry I don't know much about all this just saw a tutorial and uploaded my laravel project can you please explain or provide instructions how to solve this.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#nginx

Comment: @lagbox So if just add this in  my ``index.php`` :- ```location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}``` it will work right?

Comment: no, you will have to adjust your nginx configuration for the site

Comment: @lagbox Thankyou. but can you please guide me how to do that.

Comment: do you have a file named `/etc/nginx/sites-available/{yourwebsite}.com` in production or created while when uploading the project

Comment: @bhucho no I don't think so, I never made such file in the process of uploading